# How to export neo4j graph into edgelist format?

Tags: neo4j, export, graph-databases

I have large neo4j graph. Is there any way I can export it into [edgelist](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/readwrite.edgelist.html) format?

Any links or pointers to external utilities or libraries would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great article on how to use `jq` to produce csv output, see https://neo4j.com/blog/export-csv-from-neo4j-curl-cypher-jq/. I assume you can use the very same approach to generate edgelist.